# make a telegram bot - ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.client.HttpClient

Tags: java, telegram-bot

I have a big problem :

I want to make a  very simple  Telegram Bot  .

---

and I've searched a lot of websites  and I found this code but I got this error when running following code :

I tried in Eclipse but the error is same and it's about `ClassLoader`

---

I don't know what  is the problem and what to do ?

```
C:\Users\HM\.jdks\openjdk-16.0.2\bin\java.exe "-javaagent:E:\IntelliJ IDEA 
Community Edition 2021.1.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=51246:E:\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 
2021.1.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath 

C:\Users\HM\IdeaProjects\telegramNew\out\production\telegramNew
;C:\Users\HM\Desktop\telegram 
bots-5.3.0.jar;C:\Users\HM\Desktop\telegrambots-meta-5.3.0.jar com.company.Main
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/HttpClient
at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:636)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
... 1 more
```

**My main method:**

```
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.TelegramBotsApi;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.exceptions.TelegramApiException;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.updatesreceivers.DefaultBotSession;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
      TelegramBotsApi botsApi = new TelegramBotsApi(DefaultBotSession.class);

      botsApi.registerBot(new MyBot());
    } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
}
```

**My Bot :**

```
import org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.TelegramLongPollingBot;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.methods.send.SendMessage;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.Update;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.exceptions.TelegramApiException;

public class MyBot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {

  @Override
  public String getBotUsername() {
    return "hamidComputerBot";
  }

  @Override
  public String getBotToken() {
    return "1909766145:AAF7rk22xEbtM45zUm4RVCpK3MNpjuD52lI";
  }

  @Override
  public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {

    if (update.hasMessage() && update.getMessage().hasText()) {
      SendMessage message = new SendMessage(); // Create a SendMessage object with 
      mandatory fields
      message.setChatId(update.getMessage().getChatId().toString());
      message.setText(update.getMessage().getText());

      try {
        execute(message); // Call method to send the message
      } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You must also provide a classpath at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same trouble.
You should import maven lib with `transitive dependencies` (look below how it looks in Intellij Idea).
It required because some parts of telegram Api use this classes which is not included in `telegram bots-5.3.0.jar`

[image]